# captured image not in full size when passed to an intent

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am building an app that can capture an image then pass it to an intent. Below is the camera activity...

```
Camera.PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Bitmap bitmapPicture;

        try {
            String filename = "bitmap.jpg";
            FileOutputStream stream = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            bitmapPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arg0, 0, arg0.length);
            bitmapPicture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

            stream.close();
            bitmapPicture.recycle();

            Intent in1 = new Intent(Camera.this, ReceivePicture.class);
            in1.putExtra("image", filename);
            startActivity(in1);
            Log.i("Look here!", "Image size:"+bitmapPicture.getWidth()
                    + "x" + bitmapPicture.getHeight());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

Here is where I pass the captured photo...

```
private Bitmap bitmapPicture;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.receive);
    String filename = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");

    try {
        FileInputStream is = this.openFileInput(filename);
        bitmapPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        is.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
ImageView viewBitmap = findViewById(R.id.bitmapview);
viewBitmap.setImageBitmap(bitmapPicture);


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bitmapview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    />
```

The picture returns like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRnOI.png)

Do you have any idea why is the picture is not on its full size? Thank you in advance!

Comment: try adding `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to your image view

Comment: I tried that already :/ but the result is a cropped picture.

Comment: so what do you want?  read about different `scaleType` [here] it will help you understand what you need to do.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with capturing images. You will see it with every image file that resides on your device. Try them all.

Comment: Nor does it have anything to do with what you call 'passing to an intent'.

Comment: `bitmapPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);`. So now you have a bitmap. But what are you doing to display it? You omitted the crucial.

Comment: @greenapps ImageView viewBitmap = findViewById(R.id.bitmapview); -for displaying the picture

Comment: That code does not display a bitmap. And you better update your post with the right code. Dont put it in comments.

Comment: I edited my code. thanks @greenapps

Comment: REPEAT: `Your problem has nothing to do with capturing images. You will see it with every image file that resides on your device. Try them all. `

Comment: REPEAT: `Nor does it have anything to do with what you call 'passing to an intent'.` While you only pass a file name. A file path.

Comment: @greenapps sorry I don't get it. So, what do you think is the right approach for me to get the desired result? I think this has nothing to do with the xml file.

Comment: `So, what do you think is the right approach for me to get the desired result?` Sorry. I dont know. But if you would have asked "what do you think is the right approach for me to  post my problem?" then i would have told you to omit all about taking a picture and using an intent but only tell that you tried to load an image file in an ImageView and that it looked diffrent as you expected.